# Should we do something with tags 'resizing-window' and 'multiple-windows'?

Tags: discussion, tags

I was astonished to see that [this question/revision](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/revisions/136367/1) did not have a tag related to the concept of *window*.

While trying to edit the tags to add one, I realized that all the tags that were related to 'window' were [resizing-window](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resizing-window) and [multiple-windows](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiple-windows).

Since none of them fitted the question, I created [window-management](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/window-management) which was still appropriate and broader.

Should we keep `resizing-window` and `multiple-windows`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since both 'old' tags are not very 'popular' (16 questions for [resizing-window](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/resizing-window) and 5 questions for [multiple-windows](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/multiple-windows)) and don't contain a description, and since [window-management](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/window-management) covers window-resizing and multiple-windows, **I suggest we make them synonym of `window-management`**.

With the question "are you an expert in [tag]?", I would argue that if one is an expert in `window-resize`, or in `multiple-windows`, they're pretty knowledgeable in `window-management`.

Comment: I have made these changes.